# Show a curve is not smooth in any neighborhood

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, curves

Show that the curve $x^2-y^2=0$ is not smooth in any neighborhood of the point(0,0).
The formal definition of a smooth curve is: "A set $S$ is a smooth curve if

(a) $S$ is connected, and

(b) every $a\in S$ has a neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ such $S$ and $\mathcal{N}$ is the graph of a $C^1$ function $f$."

The question seems obvious if we just look at the graph, but how do we explain it through the definition of smooth curve?

Comment: When I look at this, it feels like we can use Implicit Function Theorem to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

First, this curve is union of the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. Let's pick $a=(0,0)$. For any neighborhood $N$ around $a$, we can apply the vertical line test to see that $x^2-y^2=0$ is not even a function so this obviously violates (b).